# Seperate two NIC´s in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have two NIC´s on my server (it does not show on the pic but they both show up at where 2 points at) and only one profile (that is where 1 points to, I don´t know if I am using the correct words to describe what is in the picture so I prefer numbers). What I would like is to have one NIC show up in the Domain Network and the other NIC to show up in the Public Network (not shown in the picture) but for the life of me I can´t figure out how to separate the two, they always show up both in the Domain network. I want this so I can apply two separate rules on the firewall. One rule for public and one rule for domain.

I have tried to delete the NIC and reinstall it, still it shows up under Domain, I have looked at `Merge or delete networks` under `Set network properties` which is the window that comes up if I click the House icon that nr 1 points at, but I am not sure what I can do there.

Any clue as to how to separate the two?

[image: Sample of network and sharing center]

EDIT: I have looked through the [Network Location Awereness](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles.aspx) article without finding my solution, I have looked through group policy and the NWA is not overridden there, I have looked through local security policy and set Unidentified Networks there as Public, still this NIC is detected as part of the Domain profile (though, I am not certain, what I did is just disable the NIC and reenable it, does that perhaps not retrigger the NWA processs?). I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Why are you multihoming this DC? What are the DNS setting on the `public` NIC?

Comment: @joeqwerty I want to provide a VPN access on the public NIC. The DNS on that one is a public DNS that it is connected to (not the same DNS as the LAN NIC is connected to).

Answer (score 0):

Windows is figuring this out for you based on your Domain policies and network settings. Are both NIC's plugged into the same subnet or have the same default gateway?

If not then it could be that there is a config issue somewhere and both your domain network and the secondary network are being zoned as DOMAIN. Probably from within Group policy and firewall policy.

Comment: This is on the domain controller (the picture is from another computer). One NIC is plugged into a switch connected to the LAN (192.168.0.0) the other NIC is plugged into a WAN switch serviced by a Cisco router (subnet 1.2.3.0/24 lets say).

Comment: And do you have any idea of where that config might be that zones networks to Domain? This is a server I did not set up so I don´t know the ins and outs of it unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise you were referring to a DC  - rather than trying to type out a long winded response the ins and out of NLA are covered in this TechNet article - http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles.aspx